# Is there a way to implement offline geocoding on an offline openstreetmaps sqlite map tile database in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, maps, geocoding, offline, openstreetmap

I have displayed openstreetmaps tiles using map2sqlite in my iPhone app. Now I wanna implement gecoding features like showing a marker on a specific location in the offline map. Any ideas?

Comment: I know from server side apps that you will need a LOT of data unless you use a web service do some sort.

Comment: Can you suggest which way is the most feasible for implementing offline maps in an app?

Answer (score 0):

Well map rendering and geocoding are very different requirements to the structures of a geospatial dataset.
AFAIK there is currently no geocoder for iPhone, just the [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)  server.

If you are not afraid of the amount of data, you might use http://www.geonames.org as starting point for a own lib. Or you analyse all the processing that Nominatim does on OSM data to isolate places, addresses, roads and boundaries (that is complex and needs a precleaning of the data).